# How to pull in data into a separate cell only if it does not contain a certain word?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My bench sheets are coded to display alerts when values are above or below limits. When the value is in the range, it is coded as "Good". I am struggling to write code that pulls in the the warnings when there is an issue with a result and not pull it in when the result is within range.

The code that I using below pulls everything in. I am looking for a modification that excludes "GOOD".

```
=IF($J$14="","",$J$14)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
=IF(or($J$14="",$J$14="Good"),"",$J$14)
```

But you might need:

```
=IF(or($J$14="",$J$14="Good",$J$14="GOOD"),"",$J$14)
```

if the text is case sensitive...